# Page gets blank randomly Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, cache, magento2.2.2

Site is built on version "2.2.2" and strangely page shows blank at random period untill we cleared the cache. Anyone has faced similar issue?

Already checked https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9050 but not sure what's the solution they have added.

Answer (score 0):

please do

> rm -rf generated/*
>
> rm -rf var/cache/*
>
> rm -rf var/page-cache/*

Comment: It works when I clear the cache as I mention, but I need to know why it gets blank at first place randomly